# Как подключить curses-подобную библиотеку?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, библиотеки, ncurses

Платформа Windows 10.
Хочу поработать с curses-подобной библиотекой, но возникли проблемы. Не получается их подключить.

Через MinGW установил GCC, make, ncurses, pdcurses, gdb.

Пытаюсь сначала работать через Visual Studio, устанавливаю библиотеки из NuGet, но как подключить её не пойму

```
#include <ncurses.h>
```

Строка подчеркивается красным курсивом. Соответственно она не подключена.

Если я работаю с VS Code, то строка также красная. Указал путь в c/c++ расширении до компилятора, стандартные библиотеки заработали, curses нет.

Пытался через msys2, тоже не получается.

1.Как подключить curses-подобные библиотеки?
Желательно через gcc, а не компилятор VC++(если он так правильно называется)

2.Есть ли способ поменять компилятор в Visual Studio, или он залочен на VC++?(менее важный)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не смешивайте MinGW и VS, библиотеки от одного чаще всего не совместимы с другим.

---

> Пытался через msys2

Для начала, прочитайте [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552265/2752075). Я буду использовать UCRT64, но для других должно быть аналогично.

Ищем библиотеку: `pacman -Ss curses`

Видим:

```
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-curses
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-ncurses
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pdcurses
```

Гуглеж подсказывает, что [в MSYS2 первое - синоним третьего](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pdcurses) (смотрим в "provides"), и что третье - лучше чем второе.

Ставим: `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pdcurses`.

Теперь пробуем собрать hello world.

```
#include <pdcurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscr();
    printw("Hello World !!!");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Смотрим [список файлов в пакете](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pdcurses). Там нет .pc-файла, поэтому не получится использовать `pkgconf`, чтобы автоматически, не думая, получить правильные флаги компилятора.

Видим несколько .a-файлов, из которых нужно выбрать. (А вот и [мануал](https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCursesMod?tab=readme-ov-file#ports).) Пробуем каждый:

- `g++ 1.cpp -lpdcurses` - открывает свое окно, которое выглядит как простенькая консоль
- `g++ 1.cpp -lpdcurses_vt` - пытается что-то печатать в обычную консоль, но у меня в wine нормально не заработал.
- `g++ 1.cpp -lpdcurses_wincon -lwinmm` - печатает в консоль (откуда взялся `-lwinmm` - сначала пробуем без него, видим ошибку `undefined reference to PlaySoundW` - открываем [мануал](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) - там видим `Library - Winmm.lib` - подставляем `-lwinmm`, ошибка пропадает)
- `g++ 1.cpp -lpdcurses_wingui -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lcomdlg32` - аналогично первому (флаги подбирал как в предыдущем пункте)

В итоге, wincon выглядит лучше всего.

---

Если захотите сделать то же самое на Visual Studio, я бы использовал vcpkg. (Теоретически vcpkg и с MinGW кое-как работает, но привязываться к нему выглядит странно - все-таки он больше для VS, MinGW там для галочки, насколько я понимаю.)

Есть еще Conan, который должен работать и с MinGW, и с VS.

NuGet - это какой-то странный зверь, я не видел, чтобы им пользовались для С++.

---

> 2.Есть ли способ поменять компилятор в Visual Studio, или он залочен на VC++?

Там можно легко можно поставить Clang (в режиме совместимости с MSVC (то что вы называете "VC++")).

Способ поставить другие-то может и есть, но зачем? Если не используете MSVC, то я бы не привязывался с продуктам MS (по крайней мере не-кроссплатформенным и не-опенсурсным). Я бы посоветовал VSCode (с Clangd вместо дефолтного C++-плагина - во-первых опенсорс, во-вторых работает лучше). Потом будет легче мигрировать на другую ОС, и опенсорс не превратится неожиданно в тыкву от санкций и прочего.

Comment: Кто минус обронил? Я не могу исправить ошибки в ответе, если я про них не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, минус не ронял. Ясно теперь что лучше использовать msys2, т.к. работает с vs.  Установил gcc, gdb, pdcurses через ucrt_64, все указал. Еще покопавшись понял, что надо было также указывать includePath для загруженных библиотек, а я-то думал что указал компилятор и усе. Само заработает... Если честно второй день только разбираюсь, всего не знаю. Начиная со слов "Смотрим список файло..."  и до "wincon выглядит лучше всего" лично для меня мало что понятно. Пока с VS и vcpkg(узнать бы что это такое) связываться не хочу. Я хочу уже попробовать код написать.

Comment: Что такое Conan не знаю, использовал инструменты, которые первым нарыл. NuGet по всей видимости продукт MS, пока тоже оставлю. Clang ставить не хочу, готовлюсь в School21, там насколько знаю gcc, не знаю разница большая или нет, повторюсь, что изучаю не так давно. По проблеме. Сейчас курсив пропал, но все равно не компилируется, ссылается json(тоже дебри) и что-то связанное с загрузкой. Груз на Вас не кладу, сам покопаюсь, надеюсь решу, но буду рад если прокомментируете.
https://ibb.co/pLKQWxL
https://ibb.co/KsnbgDF

Comment: @АртурНигматуллин *"лучше использовать msys2, т.к. работает с vs"* Не, они вместе как раз не работают. Или вы про VSC? С VSC в принципе все работает. *"надо было также указывать includePath для загруженных библиотек"* То, что я сказал, влияет именно на компиляцию. `includePath` влияет только на подсказки в VSC (но для, для комфортной работы он тоже нужен). *"Начиная со слов "Смотрим список файло...""* Есть такая штука, называется `pkgconf` (или другой его вариант `pkg-config`). Это - мелкая программа, которая говорит, какие флаги компилятора нужны, чтобы подключить ту или иную библиотеку. ...

Comment: ... Но она работает только если с библиотекой поставляется файл с расширением .pc, где эти флаги написаны. Все приличные либы его поставляют, но pdcurses - нет. Поэтому дальше флаги подбираются вручную. Я смотрю на .a в списке файлов. .a - это скомпилированная (статическая) библиотка. Например, флаг `-lpdcurses` подключает библиотеку `libpdcurses.a` (или `libpdcurses.dll.a`, но тут не так важно) - то есть добавляется префикс `lib` и расширение `.a`. Если не указать `-l...` а только заинклудить хедер и позвать функцию оттуда, на вас посыпятся ошибки `undefined reference to какая-то-функция`.

Comment: @АртурНигматуллин *"но все равно не компилируется, ссылается json"* У меня ссылки не открываются, загрузите на pastebin?

Comment: что-то сам забыл что имел ввиду, все действия проводил на VSC.  Не понял ваше замечание по поводу includePath, без указания папки include, pdcurses не хотел подключаться. С pkgconf познакомлюсь, думаю, позже. Пока вожусь с проблемами, приведенными выше, в виде ссылок на картинки.

Comment: в ссылках не код, а скрины диалоговых окон

Comment: @АртурНигматуллин Ну они все равно не открываются у меня из Казахстана. На imgur скрины можно.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QbsgP3u

Comment: Покажите launch.json, tasks.json, и что он печатает в терминал перед тем как так ругнуться.

Comment: https://youtu.be/p2wI64uLrFg

Comment: @АртурНигматуллин Полный лог из терминала на pastebin, пожалуйста. Он на видео мгновенно пролетает, ничего не разглядеть.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qXRxmNRF

Comment: @АртурНигматуллин Я не вижу тут флагов `-lpdcurses_wincon -lwinmm`, значит не вписали их в tasks.json.